# Access Excel cell value in c#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Cell A1 contains value "=A2"
Cell A2 contains "Microsoft".

When I access cell A1 through c# I get "Microsoft".

How to access "=A2"  value of cell A1?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell //it points to address A1
object obj=cell.Value2; //Here obj contains "Microsoft" but I want "=A2"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use Range.Formula:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell //it points to address A1
object obj=cell.Formula;
```